# Custom extension does not get activated

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I've been developing a VSCode extension (https://github.com/openSUSE/vscode-daps), originally on openSUSE Linux. There, everything worked fine. After trying it out on Debian 12, i found that it does not get activated and all registered commands are not found. But when I run the same extension from the VSCode Debugging session, everything works fine? Any idea why this extension is not activated? 2 other extensions work fine on both distros.

Comment: Developer tools revealed that `Activating extension 'openSUSE.daps' failed: Cannot find module 'xmldom'` - how can i include it in the extension?

Comment: the extension xmldom is deprecated in foavour of  '@xmldom/xmldom'. but after requiring it and running `npm install @xmldom/xmldom`, i receive an error message `Activating extension 'openSUSE.daps' failed: Cannot find module '@xmldom/xmldom'`

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I deleted the whole `node_modules` directory, rebuilt it with `npm install` and the most important thing is DO NOT IGNORE the `node_modules` directory when building the extension package. It means that there should be no

```
node_modules/**
```

line in the extension's `.vscodeignore` file

good luck :-)